# Nested Array error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

It's first time using Room Database and I wanted to save my data into Nested Class

Plant Class:

```js
@Entity
data class Plant(

    @PrimaryKey  var id:Long,
    @ColumnInfo (name="plant_name") var name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name ="plant_type") var type: Plant_Category,
    @ColumnInfo(name= "plant_image") var image: Int,

    ) {

}
```

This is the PlantCategory Class :

```js
@Entity
data class Plant_Category(

    @PrimaryKey var id: Int =0,
    @ColumnInfo(name="plant_type_name") var type:String ="",
    @ColumnInfo(name="plant_type_water")var water_time: String ="",
    @ColumnInfo(name="plant_type_details")var details: String = "",){
}
```

I tried using

```
@TypeConverter  or @SerializedName
```

But it seems those annotations are not available
Perhaps I'm missing a library ?

here is my gradle file:

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    //Room database
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
    //coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.2'
    //Viewmodel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
    //LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1"
    //ui
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    //navigation
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    //views
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    //testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

I will be grateful for your help!

Comment: `@TypeConverter` is defined in `androidx.room:room-common`. You are getting that as a transitive dependency from `androidx.room:room-runtime`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Alright I will try it

Comment: @CommonsWare What about  ```@SerializedName```? I think it's still need Serialized name because it's still give me same error.

Comment: `@SerializedName` is not part of Room. The most common place I see that annotation is with Gson (`com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName`) for converting objects to/from JSON. You *could* use Gson in a `@TypeConverter` for converting some type to/from a `String` for storing in the database, but there are other JSON libraries (e.g., Moshi) and other ways of implementing a `@TypeConverter`.

Comment: Ah thank you for you answer I managed to figure to get rid of the error using ```@Embedded```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to Insert it would be easier to do this:

```
@Entity
data class Plant(

    @PrimaryKey  var id:Long,
    @ColumnInfo (name="plant_name") var name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name ="plant_type") var type: Plant_Category,
    @ColumnInfo(name= "plant_image") var image: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name="plant_type_name") var type:String ="",
    @ColumnInfo(name="plant_type_water")var water_time: String ="",
    @ColumnInfo(name="plant_type_details")var details: String = "",


    ) {

}
```

And if you want to have a specific entity for Category where you insert new plant types you can also have  this entity.

```
@Entity
data class Plant_Category(

    @PrimaryKey var id: Int =0,
    @ColumnInfo(name="plant_type_name") var type:String ="",
    @ColumnInfo(name="plant_type_water")var water_time: String ="",
    @ColumnInfo(name="plant_type_details")var details: String = "",){
}
```

It would be easier for to manage :)

Comment: Yeah I did ended up doing like that